# Complex Numbers Geometry

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I'm not sure where to begin on this problem - do I plug in for a and solve for z? 
I was also given a hint:

Let z be a point on the line we're trying to describe. We have good tools in complex numbers for collinearity and perpendicularity. Which would be useful here.

Here is the problem:

Let a and b be two complex numbers on the unit circle, i.e. $|a| = |b| = 1.$

(a) Show that the equation of the tangent to the unit circle at a is given by $ z + a^2 \overline{z} = 2a.$

[image]

(b) Show that the intersection of the tangents to the unit circle at a and b is $\frac{2ab}{a + b}.$

[image]

Comment: For $(b)$, what would you normally do when finding the intersection of two lines?

Comment: set the 2 equations equal to one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to use the hints you've been given, but you could solve these problems as follows.

First, note that the equation in (a) is equivalent to $\bar{a}z+a\bar{z}=2$ and the one in (b) to $(a+b)\bar{z}=2$ since $\bar{a}=1/a$ for any $a$ on the unit circle (I assume  $a+b\ne0$).

If $a=e^{i\phi}$, then the tangent line is given by $x\cos\phi+y\sin\phi=1$. You can use this to prove (a) by plugging $z=x+iy$ and $a=\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$ into my version of (a) given above and taking the products.

For (b), assume $\bar{a}z+a\bar{z}=2$ and $\bar{b}z+b\bar{z}=2$ and take the sum
$$\bar{a}z+a\bar{z}+\bar{b}z+b\bar{z}=(a+b)\bar{z}+(\bar{a}+\bar{b})z=4.$$
Note that $(a+b)\bar{z}$ is a real number since $a+b$ and $z$, which is the intersection point, have the same argument and the argument of $\bar{z}$ is the negative of that.
Therefore, $(a+b)\bar{z}=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $z$ is a point of the tangent line then:
$$z=\lambda a i +a \quad (1)$$
and
$$\bar{z}=-\lambda \bar{a} i + \bar{a} \quad (2)$$
where $\lambda$ is a real number.

Recall that if $a$ is in unit circle then:
$$a \bar{a}=1$$
Let's calculate $z+ \bar{z} a^2$:
$$z+ \bar{z} a^2=(\lambda a i +a)+(-\lambda \bar{a} i + \bar{a})a^2=2a$$
and we conclude that the statement (a) is true.

For statement (b) use twice statement (a) and solve the system, you will find that (b) is also true.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Since we know the tangent line and the radius from the origin to $a$ are perpendicular, we can say $$z-a = a(e^{\pi i/2}k) = aki$$ where $k$ is some integer.
Manipulating the equation we get:
\begin{align*}
z-a &= aki \\
z &= a(1+ki) \\
\overline{z} &= \overline{a}(1-ki) \\
a^2\overline{z} &= a^2\overline{a}(1-ki)
\end{align*}
Let's simplify the right side: $$a^2\overline{a}(1-ki) = a\cdot a\overline{a}(1-ki) = a\cdot |a|^2(1-ki) = a(1-ki)$$
Now we can continue:
\begin{align*}
a^2\overline{z} &= a^2\overline{a}(1-ki) \\
a^2\overline{z} &= a(1-ki) \\
a^2\overline{z} &= a-aki \\
a^2\overline{z} &= 2a - a - aki \\
a^2\overline{z} &= 2a - z \\
z+a^2\overline{z} &= 2a
\end{align*}

(b) Let's set $w$ as the intersecting point. Using out solution from part a, we can say: $$w+a^2\overline{w}-2a=0=w+b^2\overline{w}-2b$$
Let's manipulate this equation:
\begin{align*}
w+a^2\overline{w}-2a &= w+b^2\overline{w}-2b \\
a^2\overline{w}-b^2\overline{w} &= 2a-2b \\
\overline{w}(a^2-b^2) & = 2(a-b) \\
\overline{w}(a+b) &= 2 \\
\overline{w} &= \frac{2}{a+b} \\
w &= \frac{2}{\overline{a}+\overline{b}}
\end{align*}
Let's take a step back and figure $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$
\begin{align*}
a\overline{a} = |a|^2 \\
a\overline{a} = 1 \\
\overline{a} = \frac{1}{a}
\end{align*}
Using same logic, we can also derive $\overline{b} = \frac{1}{b}$
Now let's substitute these values in:
\begin{align*}
w &= \frac{2}{\overline{a}+\overline{b}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\frac{a+b}{ab}} \\
&= \frac{2ab}{a+b}
\end{align*}