# A formula for the Feuerbach point

Tags: reference-request, complex-numbers, triangles, plane-geometry

Did some calculations related to the [Feuerbach point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuerbach_point) with a CAS and noticed the following fact:

Consider tangents to the unit circle  in the complex plane, at points $z_k$, $k=1,2,3$, forming a triangle. The circle through the midpoints of this triangle ( the [Euler circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_circle)) is tangent to the unit circle at the Feuerbach point $z$ given by the formula

$$z = \frac{z_1 z_2 + z_1 z_3 + z_2 z_3}{z_1 + z_2 + z_3}$$

Note also that if $z_k = \frac{1+ i t_k}{1-i t_k}$, then we have $z = \frac{1+ i t}{1-i t}$, where

$$t = \frac{t_1 + t_2 + t_3+ 3 t_1 t_2 t_3}{3 + t_1 t_2 + t_1 t_3 + t_2 t_3}$$

Since we have a fairly neat [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141830/how-to-find-the-center-of-the-circle-that-contains-three-given-complex-numbers/4744438#4744438) for the center of a circle passing through $3$ points, we can get from the above a formula for the Feuerbach point, given the contact points of the incircle, or the  excircles.

This gotta be a known fact, but did not find it in other places, so any reference/source would be appreciated!

$\bf{Added:}$ This  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912551/the-slope-of-a-triangles-euler-line-in-terms-of-the-slopes-of-its-sides) has a formula similar to the second one.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an interesting document [here](https://www.turgor.ru/lktg/2019/6-Inversions%20of%20the%20Feuerbach%20point/6-1en.pdf).

Comment: @Jean Marie: Very informative, thank you!

Comment: Probably a pure coincidence, I have found (almost) the same formula in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line) for the slope $m_E$ of the Euler line...

Comment: It has taken me some time to realize that if $z_k=e^{i \alpha_k}=\frac{1+it}{1-it}$ then $t$ is nothing else than $\tan (\tfrac12 \alpha_k)$...

Comment: A connection : the theorem given [here](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2006volume6/FG200621.pdf) connecting Feuerbach point with the Euler line of a "twin triangle".

Comment: @JeanMarie:  Thanks!  I added another link in the question, check it out. I think you meant the link provided in the comments(?)

Comment: FYI: [Euclid @ groups.io](https://groups.io/g/euclid) is a geometry forum with many discussions about triangle centers.

Comment: @Blue: Thank you!  That looks like a pro forum indeed.   I looked at some books that use complex numbers in geometry (Andrica & Andreescu) but the formulas are different.

Answer (score 0):

Found this neat [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289604/lines-tangent-to-a-unit-circle-on-a-complex-plane) that helps solve the problem.

So let's start with $a$, $b$, $c$ complex numbers on the unit circle ($\bar a =1/a $, $\bar b =1/b $, $\bar c = 1/c$) The triangle formed by the tangents the the unit circle at these points has coordinates  $\frac{2 b c}{b+c}$, $\frac{2 c a}{c+a}$, $\frac{2 a b}{a+b}$ and its midpoints are

$$
\frac{ c a}{c+a}+\frac{ a b}{a+b}\  (=\colon p)\\
\frac{ a b}{a+b}+\frac{ b c}{b+c}\  (=\colon p)\\
\frac{ b c}{b+c}+\frac{ c a}{c+a}\  (=\colon r)\\
$$

Now recall the [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311896/the-equation-of-circle-in-complex-plane-passing-through-three-points/312082#312082) of a circle through three points $p$, $q$, $r$:

$$\left| \begin{matrix} 
1 & z& \bar z & |z|^2 \\
1 & p& \bar p & |p|^2 \\
1 & q& \bar q & |q|^2 \\
1 & r& \bar r & |r|^2 
\end{matrix} \right|=0$$

Such a circle has a unique point of intersection with the unit circle $\bar z = 1/z$ if and only if the equation

$$\left| \begin{matrix} 
1 & z& \frac{1}{z} & 1 \\
1 & p& \bar p & |p|^2 \\
1 & q& \bar q & |q|^2 \\
1 & r& \bar r & |r|^2 
\end{matrix} \right|=0$$

Note that

$$
\bar p= \frac{1}{c+a}+ \frac{1}{a+b}\\
\bar q = \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}\\
\bar r = \frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}
$$

Now one calculates the second determinant and gets

$$\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\cdot \left((a+b+c)z - (a b + b c + c a)\right)^2}{(a+b)^2(b+c)^2(c+a)^2 z}$$

Therefore, the unique solution of the equation is

$$z= \frac{a b + b c + c a}{a+b+c}$$